# VB.net - Mousehover not sensitive

Tags: vb.net

I made picturebox which would change if the mover is over the image but it takes too long. can someone help me please? 
Here's my code:

```
Private Sub button2_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button2.MouseHover
        button1.Visible = True
        button2.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub button1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.MouseLeave
        button1.Visible = False
        button2.Visible = True
    End Sub
```

Thanking you in advance

Comment: How long is too long? Maybe do this via MouseEnter and MouseLeave?

Comment: @Mort Thanks sir you just saved me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to adjust the time the mouse must pause over the image, the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover(v=vs.110).aspx) say;

> A typical use of `MouseHover` is to display a tool tip when the mouse pauses on a control within a specified area around the control (the "hover rectangle"). The pause required for this event to be raised is specified in milliseconds by the `MouseHoverTime` property.

To achieve that, simply change the value of `SystemInformation.MouseHoverTime` in your code.

Alternatively, as someone has commented, use a `MouseEnter` event instead, this will trigger instantly.

Comment: Thanks sir that was absolutely what I needed for my code to work

Comment: Next time check the documentation first, it's usually helpful!

Comment: Yes Sir, I'll do that for sure